# Binary String to ASCII 6bit char in Java

Tags: java

I have a long String with 48bit in Java. This string will be divided into 8 strings with a length of 6bit. Every string should be converted to an ASCII char. Therefore the Sixbit ASCII Code should be used.

Now I have a table with all the possible chars and the binary code for it. My first idea was to convert the binary string to the char by using a switch case and define a rule for every possibility, but this can't be the best option.

Is there some kind of a function, which I can use to convert this automatically and that I don't have to write a method with the switch?

Comment: A rather cool, but likely more trouble than it's worth approach would be to implement a Charset class for you 6-bit characters. Then you could just read the data as binary into strings using that character encoding.

Comment: Are you trying to describe Base-64 encoding? If yes, just use a base-64 encoder.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit character set. Do you mean you want to use the first 64 of those 128 characters?

Comment: SIXBIT is a derivative of ASCII.  Basically, if you take the numeric value of an ASCII character less than 0x60 (ie, lower-case not allowed) and subtract off 32 (0x20 hex) then you get the SIXBIT value.

Comment: @SualehFatehi no I don't mean Base-64 encoding. Here is table which was provided: http://pho.to/7nElV maybe this helps to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte sixBitFromAscii(char asciiChar) {
    if (asciiChar >= 0x60) {
        System.out.println("Invalid character " + asciiChar);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (byte)(asciiChar - 0x20);
    }
}

public char asciiFromSixBit(byte sixBit) {
    return (char) (sixBit + 0x20);
}
```

Comment: This assume a specific mapping from his 6-bit values to ASCII. There a number of standard ones, likely he's using one of those, a bit much to assume one arbitrarily.

Comment: You have a right to your opinion, I suppose.  There are no other modern 6-bit schemes, however.

Comment: if what he's encountering is something from industry, and it's modern, then you're definite spot on. If it's a class exercise where the 6-bit scheme was tossed together by an instructor, it'd pretty unlikely to be the case. I think a general solution that handles both cases is more useful unless the question says it is a standard (or otherwise structured) encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the clarification, and your posting the actual table, this becomes really simple. With the charset sorted, we can just convert directory and index into the array. Keep in mind, if you input was a String of 0/1s, you'd have to do some bit twiddling to get value (named n in this code). Otherwise, it would be the same.

```
public class sixbit {
    static final char[] CHARSET = 
        {'@','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O',
        'P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','[','\\',']','^',
        '_',' ','!','"','#','$','%','&','\'','(',')','*','+',',','-',
        '.','/','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',':',';','<',
        '=','>','?'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Sample String of length 48, maybe up of 1s and 0s
        String input = "010011010100000001000011001011001111010110010010" ;
        System.out.println(input);
        String[] parts = splitInput(input); // Split into 6-bit pieces
        for(String sixbit: parts) {
            int n = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(sixbit, 2);
            System.out.printf("%s -> %c \n", sixbit,CHARSET[n]);        
        }       
    }

    private static String[] splitInput(String input) {
        String[] parts = new String[8]; // 48 bits, 6 bits each means we get 8 characters;
        int current_part = 0;
        int current_bit = 0;
        StringBuilder sb; 
        while(current_bit < 48) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                sb.append(input.charAt(current_bit));               
                current_bit++;
            }
            parts[current_part] = sb.toString();
            current_part++;                     
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

**old version**

Other than the loadLookupTable() method only including some randomly tossed together entries your table, this should do what you want.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sixbit {
    static Map<String,Character> lookup = new HashMap<String,Character>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadLookupTable();  
        // Sample String of length 48, maybe up of 1s and 0s
        String input = "111000111001100110101000110000110100111011110111" ;
        System.out.println(input);
        String[] parts = splitInput(input); // Split into 6-bit pieces
        for(String sixbit: parts) {
            char ch = lookup.get(sixbit); // Lookup each 6-bit String to get the corresponding character.
            System.out.printf("%s -> %c \n", sixbit, ch);
        }

    }

    private static String[] splitInput(String input) {
        String[] parts = new String[8]; // 48 bits, 6 bits each means we get 8 characters;
        int current_part = 0;
        int current_bit = 0;
        StringBuilder sb; 
        while(current_bit < 48) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
                sb.append(input.charAt(current_bit));               
                current_bit++;
            }
            parts[current_part] = sb.toString();
            current_part++;                     
        }
        return parts;
    }

    private static void loadLookupTable() {
        /* For each bit string you have in your table, add the corresponding character. It would be shorter code,
         * and a touch faster to load this from an array, but it would take a bit of thought and wouldn't be as clear.
         * Grab enough to work for this example, so that this program works. Just need to make sure the full lookup is loaded
         * properly.
         */
        lookup.put("100110", 'a');
        lookup.put("100111", 'b');
        lookup.put("101000", 'c');
        lookup.put("110000", 'k');
        lookup.put("110100", 'o');
        lookup.put("110111", 'r');
        lookup.put("111000", 's');
        lookup.put("111001", 't');
        // and so on...
        lookup.put("111011", 'v');
        lookup.put("111100", 'w');
        lookup.put("111101", 'x');
        lookup.put("111110", 'y');
        lookup.put("111111", 'z');
    }
}
```

Comment: The method splitInput is not the best way of splitting a String/Array like that. I wrote it that way so it would be easy to follow based on the code snippet you post.

Answer (score -1):

Break the String into bytes (6-bits each with 2 bits of padding). Then just use an array mapping the byte values to the ASCII char value.

**edit** Ok, I misunderstood your question as you having raw binary data. Apparent you have a String of 1s and 0s, like "1010111" of length 48. The actual implementation is very different (and a lot easier). See my other answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: With padding you mean two zeros? Should the padding be in front of my 6-bits or after the 6-bits?

Comment: Two bits, zeros or ones, doesn't matter. The idea is just to convert 6-bit value to a byte, so you have normal Java value to index an array off of. Have a lookup take of char[] that is indexed by the byte values.

Comment: I tried something, but I don't know why I don't get any output. Is this how you mean it? http://pho.to/7nE66

Comment: I mean actual bits and bytes, not Strings.

Comment: So I should convert my string to a byte?

Comment: Is your input a Java String of 1s and 0s? like "101010010101010101" that is 48 long? I had (mis)read it that you had actual binary data.